# Redirect after facebook login iPhone or iOS devices

Tags: javascript, facebook, ios7, facebook-javascript-sdk, mobile-safari

I am using javascript facebook SDK to build a login flow and check if user likes a page, so far so good it works fine except in iPhone web app view, there after login (both method login button or calling FB.login API function) does not redirect me back to configured url in facebook app settings.

in iPad, web app view (aka home screen shortcut), login dialog does not render at all. killing... 
It works flawless in desktop browsers, Android browsers, Chrome but not on iOs devices.

iPhone at least opens a dialog with login window but no redirect.

What I tried so far, is

1. Manual location.href but no effect in mobile web app view
2. Checked configured url in page settings, also it works everywhere else excpet iOs devices, so less probable
3. addred display:touch and redirect_uri in scope parameter of FB.login call
4. use direct url with oAuth [https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={app-id}&redirect_uri={redirect-uri}](https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=%7Bapp-id%7D&redirect_uri=%7Bredirect-uri%7D)
5. Took example from facebook developer site as is 
   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.0
6. Cursed FB API 1000 times.......for such an inconsistent behavior
7. Followed so many threads all over the web...nothing helps.

Here is the test page, if you want to see whats going wrong...

http://www.villa-westend.nl/test.html

Any help is appreciated. I am out of ideas now.

Thank you.

Comment: I assume you request user_likes to get the users likes? You are aware that if you created your app after 4/30/2014 you will have to get that permission reviewed by Facebook. And Facebook will not grant it if you just use it for like-gating.

If you created your app before that date you will only be able to use it for 11 more months until you are forced to get reviewed

Comment: Thanks WizKid, I didn't know that. App is created before 30-04-2014 and it works everywhere except ios devices. Tried iPhone 3, 4, 5 with iOS 5,7. My doubt was and is on FB api inconsistent behavior.